# Exporting distinct images from a sprite sheet using GIMP

Tags: animation, spritesheet, png, gimp, export

I have recently found that in Photoshop there is a script that enables you to export individual images on different layers into distinct png images on disk.

Is it GIMP capable of doing the same thing and how?

I have a sprite sheet (png image) and there are 36 perfectly aligned images in 4 rows (64x64 pixels each). I have to cut and export 36 times.

Can be GIMP of some help here? I don't have Photoshop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use Guillotine to slice the image along the guides](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-guillotine.html) or take a look at [this plugin](http://registry.gimp.org/node/20868), which is used to make tiles out of an image - which is what you probably want.

Comment: although not fully automated it does what it does perfectly i.e slices all subimages into distinct gimp windows for export. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into Python and the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

I am developing my first cocos2d game and following guidance from a book, I am using the technique of slicing an image to use as the scrolling background of the game.  The author recommends having each slice on a different layer in a image-editing program and exporting them to TexturePacker.

Having spent 10 minutes, with Pixelmator, trying to figure out *how* to slice and copy each slice, and getting no where, I thought "%?@$ that!" and turned to scripting.

1. It took 30 seconds to install `py27-pil` using macports.
2. It took me 30 minutes to develop a python script and allows an input image to be sliced into n-pieces (and I am no Python expert).
3. It takes 3 seconds to run the script (the input is 2048x1534).

Here's [a link](https://gist.github.com/trojanfoe/9255303) to the script, if anyone's interested.